# My network image not uploading. there are showing these error,

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-dependencies

```
Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = 'E:\flutter practice\flutter_practice\images\https:\\mofa.gov.pk\wp-content\uploads\2019\11' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, errno = 123)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(
  MaterialApp(
  title: 'my app',
      home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('this is my app bar title'),),
          body: Image.network("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"),
          )

  ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I'd assume the problem is not with the Network image, but rather with something else. whats the output of `flutter doctor -v`? also, try `flutter clean` and `fluttter pub get`. also, check the `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Good Answeer, issue resolved by your suggestion